# Submitting a collection of ROS mercurial/git/bzr repositories

Tags: ros, wiki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Currently our lab has a rather primitive single repository indexed by ROS that holds a whole bunch of unrelated stacks.  I'd like to split these out into individual repositories, yet still have them indexed together under our lab banner, as a number of other groups seem to have done.

It's not obvious to me how to do this outside of svn.  Do I create an overarching repository that simply holds the .rosinstall file for the various other repositories, and submit the address of this repository and .rosinstall to ros-users?  And will modifying the .rosinstall in future allow me to add new stacks?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34262/submitting-a-collection-of-ros-mercurial/git/bzr-repositories/) by [Liz Murphy](https://answers.ros.org/users/425/liz-murphy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2012-05-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think it's best to have one repository per stack. To have all repositories indexed, you can provide a rosinstall file that contains all your repositories. This rosinstall file needs to be accessible by a URL, i.e. it's not really necessary to have it in a repository. I like to have it under version control though. For each run, the indexer reads this rosinstall file, i.e. when you change it, the indexer will use the updated file.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-05-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2